# Remove php without breaking Lampp

Tags: php, uninstall, lamp, elementaryos

While trying to run a Symfony app, I'm getting an Exception that states I don't have the PDO drivers installed properly. When running the corresponding actions, I've noticed I've two php packages installed in my ElementaryOS

1. php
2. php from Lampp (xampp for linux)

Because, when I execute:

```
me:/$ which php  
/usr/bin/php  

me:/$ ls /opt/lampp/bin/php  
php
```

So I would like to remove the "standalone" php. I still want to keep working with lampp, so:

How should I remove the php library that was installed previous to lampp, while avoiding breaking any stuff from lampp?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the PHP PDO module was turned on for standalone PHP.

All you need to do is to turn on the PHP PDO for PHP LAMPP - you should include the PHP PDO module into the configuration file of the PHP LAMPP.